# C++ DLL duplication of function

Tags: c++, windows, dll, shared

let's say I have got following structure of files

```
EXE
A.h <- A class header
A.cpp <- A class definition
main.cpp <- main function, with call to dll
 {
   A a;
   dllExported(a)
 }

Dll
dllExported.h
dllExported.cpp
 {
    a.fun();
 }
```

Is there a way to build Dll and Exe such as fun code won't be duplicated in both binaries.
And also does linux .so libs by default don't duplicate fun, and it's windows specific ?

Edit:
One more question, suppose I have defined global variable in A.cpp, and have extern ... in A.h will the variable be duplicated in Dll and Exe ? and how to prevent that.

Comment: Which code - A and its methods? Yes, you can put the definition of A in the DLL. Just like Linux, Windows will put the code where you tell it to and dynamically link it as needed. (Or have I misunderstood the question?)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to compile DLL without a.fun() in it, so that it will be resolved at runtime / loading of library, is it even possible ?

Comment: Put the class in the DLL and import it into your executable

Comment: Is it virtual? If yes then the DLL just needs to include the A.h and it should just work. If not, then if you mean resolve it from the .exe then that'd be difficult to do, if you're creating a circular dependency between the exe and the dll. If you really don't want to put A in this DLL then you could put it in a second DLL and have both the EXE and this DLL depend on that?